# Sql SUM only when when value = Yes

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

- `Order` as master table with the columns OrderID, Amount, date, customer, Amount
- `OrderDetails` as child table with the columns Id, OrderID, Item, status Boolean (yes or No),  Price, quantity, SubTotal.

I want sum the subtotal only if the status is YES, then show the Sum in "amount" column in the master

```
SELECT 
    Order.OrderId, Order.Date, Order.Customer, Order.Amount, 
    SUM(OrderDetails.SubTotal ) AS TotalAmount,  
FROM 
    Order 
INNER JOIN  
    OrderDetails ON Order.OrderId =  OrderDetails.OrderId    
WHERE 
    (OrderId.status = Yes)
GROUP BY 
    Order.OrderId, Order.Date, Order.Customer, Order.Amount
```

This SQL statement only returns lines where the column `Status` is "Yes", but I want to return all of them but `SUM` only the lines with `Status = Yes`.

Example:

`OrderDetails` table

```
Order-Id    item   Price   Quantity   SubTotal   Status
-------------------------------------------------------
M1          Shirt   10       10         100      yes
M1          item2    5        5          25      no
M2          Item3    7        5          35      yes
```

`Order`:

```
order-Id    date          Cus            Amount
------------------------------------------------
M1          2016/8/20     Jean-Claude      100
M2          2016/8/20     Pierre            35
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT o.OrderId, o.Date, o.Customer, o.Amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN od.status = 'YES' THEN od.SubTotal ELSE 0 END)) AS TotalAmount
FROM Order o INNER JOIN 
     Orderdetails od
     ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId
GROUP BY o.OrderId, o.Date, o.Customer, o.Amount;
```

The key is conditional aggregation -- having a `CASE` expression as the argument to the `SUM()`.

Comment: Note-  if you are using SQL 2012 or later, you could use the `iif` function in place of the `case` statement

Comment: @iliketocode . . . There is absolutely no reason to use `iif()`.  It is an unnecessary function added for back-compatibility to MS Access. `CASE` is ANSI standard and available in virtually all databases.